# How to remove background a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview

I would like to just show my cell's but when I using collection view it show a white background. is there any way to remove white background to nothing ?

[image]

Comment: use clear color

Comment: releted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570309/collectionview-background-clearcolor-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the color to clear and the background view to an empty view . call the following line in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.yourcollectionViewName?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.yourcollectionViewName?.backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

**or another choice with out code**

go to **inspector Attribute**, select the **background color field** in the storyboard and  Change it to **Clear** Color.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `backgroundColor` to `.clear`:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```